# Detecting actual arity of template template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm fiddling around with template metaprogramming, specifically with type sequences and STL-like algorithms working on those sequences. One thing I ran into was the transformation of predicates, for example by binding one of their parameters

I think it's hard to describe my problem without first providing some background information. Here's an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Type sequence
template<class... T>
struct typeseq
{
    static constexpr size_t Size = sizeof...(T);
};

// Some algorithm
template<class TS, template<class...> class P>
using remove_if = /* ... some template logic ... */;

// Usage example:
using a = typeseq<int, float, char*, double*>;
using b = remove_if<a, std::is_pointer>;   // b is typeseq<int, float>
```

As shown here, `remove_if` requires a predicate that serves as an oracle for the removal algorithm to determine which of the elements to remove. As we're dealing with metaprogramming, it is in the form of a template template parameter. **(** Note that `P` is using a variadic template parameter here. Although I'm expecting a unary template, an earlier version of C++ had the restriction that a variadic template argument can't be used as a non-variadic template parameter, which severely restricts predicate transformations. **)**  It requires that the predicate, when instantiated, resolves to a type that has a nested compile time `value` member that is convertible to `bool`.

All is well, but say you want to remove every type that is convertible to `int`. Obviously, `std::is_convertible` is a binary predicate, but `remove_if` above requires a unary predicate. We just need to fix the second template argument to `int`. Let's define a `bind2nd`:

```
template<template<class, class...> class P, class BIND>
struct bind2nd
{
    template<class T1, class... Tn> using type = P<T1, BIND, Tn...>;
};

// and now we should be able to do:
using c = remove_if<ts, bind2nd<std::is_convertible, int>::type>;   // c is typeseq<char*, double*>;
```

Unfortunately, this fails to compile on latest Clang and MSVC++. Apparently, the issue is the pack expansion of `Tn...` into `std::is_convertible<T1, BIND, Tn...>` while `std::is_convertible` only has 2 template parameters. It doesn't seem to matter that the pack is empty in practice ([isolated example](https://godbolt.org/z/PHLjZv))

I'd rather not provide 'overloads' for any required arity of the predicate passed into `bind2nd`. Is there a way to detect the arity of `P` in `bind2nd` above? GCC allows me to partially specialize it for non-variadic versions of `P`:

```
template<template<class, class> class P, class BIND>
struct bind2nd<P, BIND>
{
    template<class T1> using type = P<T1, BIND>;
};
```

But unfortunately GCC wasn't the one that was complaining in the first place. I also doubt how conformant such a partial specialization is. Is there a way around this? Is it possible to detect the actual arity of a template template parameter, and do something different based on that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a workaround.

The problem seems related to type aliases - they seem to directly pass along any template arguments, rather than instantiating the type as is the case with a class or struct. We can use this in our favor, by using a struct as an intermediate step:

```
template<template<class, class...> class P, class BIND>
struct bind2nd
{
    template<class... Tn>
    struct impl
    {
        using type = P<Tn...>;
    };
    template<class T1, class... Tn> using type = typename impl<T1, BIND, Tn...>::type;
};
```

[Now it works](https://godbolt.org/z/fLzqMK) :). It's a bit convoluted though. I wonder if this is all according to standard, but it seems to compile on all major compilers.

**Edit**: Why am I complicating things by using nested types and aliases? I can just as well use derivation for predicates:

```
template<template<class, class...> class P, class BIND>
struct bind2nd
{
    template<class T1, class... Tn>
    struct type : P<T1, BIND, Tn...> { };
};
```

Clean and simple. And it makes it almost identical to the first definition of `bind2nd` in the OP.

Comment: @bolov Thanks, that does explain a lot. Also, not sure why I'm so keen in using aliases, while I can just as well use base classes. I've expanded my answer.